# Trying to force a RewriteRule Redirect with status code 200 for missing file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpresponse, http-response-codes

Don't get angry right away :P, I am exploring options and I am having a reason for looking into this.

I (can) have script files in a folder `/scripts/competitions/*.js`.

Now, a script files will be written in this folder by a serverside script.
So at some point, a specific competition script file might not be available.
So, the website trying to load that script file gets a nice 404.

Now, I can leave it at that, unless you open Dev Tools you won't notice the 404, right?
But, I rather have my server always return a 200 for that specific folder, whatever the file(s) existence.

For this url: `/scripts/competitions/A9ACCC8F-B78A-4E0D-8023-51D8F56B5C55.js`

My current rewrite code loads the file fine, but doesn't change the status code tot 201 ( just a test).

```
ReWriteRule ^/scripts/competitions/([^.]*).js$ /scripts/competitions/$1.js [R=201]
```

So I reckon the regex is not catching correctly.

When I change it to

```
ReWriteRule ^scripts/competitions/([^.]*).js$ /scripts/competitions/$1.js [R=201]
```

It does redirect to 201 but give me an error message under the Created heading

> ### Created
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at tracker.test.local Port 80

So that one is catching, redirecting but not loading the script file IF it does exists (it did exist for that error message test).

So what I am after is a normal 200 response plus the JS body when it exists and 200 plus empty body (most preferred if possible) or the error message that file cannot be found.

A dump from my log for the first rewrite rule (starting with `^/`):

```
[Tue Nov 24 20:51:40.594882 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 3593:tid 139723926361856] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.6:55261] 192.168.1.6 - - [tracker.test.local/sid#7f14130f5618][rid#7f14130540a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/tracker/root/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/tracker/root/scripts/competitions/A9ACCC8F-B78A-4E0D-8023-51D8F56B5C55.js -> scripts/competitions/A9ACCC8F-B78A-4E0D-8023-51D8F56B5C55.js
[Tue Nov 24 20:51:40.595077 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 3593:tid 139723926361856] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.6:55261] 192.168.1.6 - - [tracker.test.local/sid#7f14130f5618][rid#7f14130540a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/tracker/root/] applying pattern '^/scripts/competitions/([^.]*).js$' to uri 'scripts/competitions/A9ACCC8F-B78A-4E0D-8023-51D8F56B5C55.js'
[Tue Nov 24 20:51:40.595313 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 3593:tid 139723926361856] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.6:55261] 192.168.1.6 - - [tracker.test.local/sid#7f14130f5618][rid#7f14130540a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/tracker/root/] pass through /var/www/test/tracker/root/scripts/competitions/A9ACCC8F-B78A-4E0D-8023-51D8F56B5C55.js
```

Hope that some one can push me in the right direction.

*update
Dump from log when file does exist and it shows a 201 but also the message that it encountered an internal error

```
[Tue Nov 24 21:27:31.134452 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 3593:tid 139723842434816] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.6:55684] 192.168.1.6 - - [tracker.test.local/sid#7f14130f5618][rid#7f14130440a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/tracker/root/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/tracker/root/scripts/competitions/A9ACCC8F-B78A-4E0D-8023-51D8F56B5C55.js -> scripts/competitions/A9ACCC8F-B78A-4E0D-8023-51D8F56B5C55.js
[Tue Nov 24 21:27:31.134479 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 3593:tid 139723842434816] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.6:55684] 192.168.1.6 - - [tracker.test.local/sid#7f14130f5618][rid#7f14130440a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/tracker/root/] applying pattern '^scripts/competitions/([^.]*)\\.js$' to uri 'scripts/competitions/A9ACCC8F-B78A-4E0D-8023-51D8F56B5C55.js'
[Tue Nov 24 21:27:31.134495 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 3593:tid 139723842434816] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.6:55684] 192.168.1.6 - - [tracker.test.local/sid#7f14130f5618][rid#7f14130440a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/tracker/root/] forcing responsecode 201 for /var/www/test/tracker/root/scripts/competitions/A9ACCC8F-B78A-4E0D-8023-51D8F56B5C55.js
```

Comment: Provide the dump regarding error please. That is what I'm interested in. The first rule fails because mod-rewrite receives the URI with leading slashes removed.

Comment: I have added the logs at the bottom of the question.  The only difference I see is Pass through and Forcing Response code. The `forcing response code` seems to be almost working but not loading the src while when it exists. Maybe a stupid path error?

Comment: Ok, I've replicated the same issue on my server.

Comment: And apparently, the same happens with status code 200

Comment: do you think it is an issue, or just a result of my/our doing something that is out of the ordinary?

Comment: I'd think that it is because of things we're doing. Although, [RFC for 201 status](https://devdocs.io/http/rfc7231#section-6.3.2) mentions that it expects ETag as validator header.

Answer (score 0):

Use server-side script as a fallback when the file doesn't exist. Also, leading directories, including slash, are stripped from `.htaccess` rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(scripts/competitions/)[^./]*\.js$ $1not_exist.php [L]
```

It doesn't have to be PHP, it could just be a static js file so it's served with the right MIME type. You just need something to return default content. Put the default in the same directory as your competition files and refer to it in your rule. The content could be:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
echo '// ', basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), ' does not exist yet.';
```